# Zend Framework 2 Json, default routing

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I am building up a user creation page (controller/module: User) which has UI controls (DOJO `filterselectbox`, `username`, etc.). The UI controls get populated with a `Json` service deployed as module (module name/controller) `myService`, and action `populatelist()`.

`populatelist` returns data as `Json` to client and the client dojo ui elements use that as a memory store.

I have 2 modules, `User` and `myService`. For the `User` module, I have setup default page as `register` and in **register.phtml** as given below. I have added logic for user input validation and data post.

`module.config.php` of module: **User**

```
'defaults' => array(
                   'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                   'action'     => 'register',
                   ),
```

Json is registered in module `myService`. **register.phtml** makes a call like:

```
myservice = new dojo.rpc.JsonService("myService/populatelist");
var dojoDeferredObject=myservice.getCategoryList();

//comment: getCtegoryList is actual method of remote object which returns the json data
```

When I open the url as **`http://localhost/user`**, any reference to `myService` JSONRPC call works perfectly fine: it parses the JSON call as **`http://localhost/myService/populatelist`** and I get the data I need.

When I access the url as **`http://localhost/user/register`**, things fail with **404 page not found** exception for every Json RPC call. Reason is, the RPC call is going on a non-existent path, i.e. **`http://localhost/user/myService/populatelist`** instead of **`http://localhost/myService/populatelist`**.

Somewhere I have missed a configuration which is resulting in this issue. I do not want to hardcode path of Json service Module `myService`.

I believe the problem is this line:

```
$server->setTarget('myService/populatelist');
```

in the below code, used to set up the Json Service. This is adding up to the path which does not exist. But I am not sure how can I control it as I want a separate module for Json service.

```
$class = "MOCAPI\Model\MOCGuest";
        $server = new Server();
        $server->setClass($class);
        //echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
            $server->setTarget('myService/populatelist')
                   ->setEnvelope(Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);
            $smd = $server->getServiceMap();
            // Set Dojo compatibility:
            $smd->setDojoCompatible(true);
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo $smd;
            return $this->getResponse();
        } else {
            //$server->handle();   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use routes and `url()` helper to build urls and relative and absolutes paths, instead of raw `'myService/populatelist'`.

Check the docs at https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html (version 2.4, but it almost the same in zf2.* and zf3).